# JAVA: Calling GUI Class from the Main class

Tags: java

So Basically, I wanted to call the GUI class in the main class but I failed to do it

```
package javaui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class JavaUI {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                RegistrationForm gui = new RegistrationForm();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(gui);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I already made a class, and I failed to load so.
 [image]

What I wanted to happen is automatically call the GUI upon starting the program.

Comment: When your program run, do you get any `error`?

Comment: Please describe "failed", since we are *probably* not sitting next to you at your desk. Also we have no idea what a `RegistrationForm` is.

Answer (score 0):

Retry after moving **RegistrationForm.java** class file under package **javaui**.